# EDI Parser in .NET

Tags: .net-3.5, edifact

Has anyone created a .NET application that reads and parses an EDI file?

EDI file - used by shipping industries to provide information on shipment invoice.

Comment: EDI is a set of standards, not a single specification. It's important to know, what exactly format the file has. For example, AS2 and AS3 protocols, which are part of EDI, use MIME-packed data which they transfer over HTTP and FTP respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a bunch out there, but none that I'm aware of for free.  Try http://www.edidev.com/FullPriceList.htm

They've been around awhile.

Answer (score 7):

An Edi Serializer for dotnet that is free and opensource is [EDI.Net](https://github.com/indice-co/EDI.Net). It supports X12, EdiFact as well as the UK only TRADACOMS formats. It even works on `dotnetcore` and `NetStandard 1.0`

**disclaimer I wrote the library*

Answer (score 5):

Check out EDIFabric on codeplex
http://edifabric.codeplex.com/

ediFabric is a .NET library (.dll) to convert EDI documents to .NET objects (or XML) and vice verse. EDI document rules are represented as .NET classes. There is one class (.cs file) per every EDI message type.

Answer (score 2):

EDIParser for .NET is another good edi parser and it written in .NET. Try http://www.sparrow-technologies.com/ediparser.net.aspx

Comment: This has the advantage of supporting both HL7 and X12 EDI (in case that's important).